# How to add column to SparkDataFrame using a set of SQL expressions?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am working with spark R and I would like to add a column to a SparkDataFrame based on a string modification of an existing column. Consider the following SparkDataFrame:

```
head(df)
  id                                                 address
  1   street_X, postal_code_X, neighborhood_X, county_name_X
  2                            neighborhood_Y, county_name_Y
  3             postal_code_Z, neighborhood_Z, county_name_Z
```

I need to add a column containing only the neighborhood. I managed to extract this column as follows into a new SparkDataFrame:

```
new_df <- selectExpr(df, "SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ',', -2) AS neighborhood")
new_df <- selectExpr(new_df, "SUBSTRING_INDEX(neighborhood, ',', 1) AS neighborhood")

head(new_df)

neighborhood
neighborhood_X
neighborhood_Y
neighborhood_Z
```

But how can I add this column neighborhood to the original df (equivalent to cbind in R/ I checked withColumn, but did not manage to combine it with selectExpr)?

Comment: Have you tried a JOIN command? A selection is a projection that selects a subset of columns, not adds new ones

Comment: Thanks, do you mean join(df, df_new)? I receive an ERROR RBackendHandler, stating that spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled should be set to true (Cartesian joins could be prohibitively expensive and are disabled by default). I need to check how to do this.

Comment: Actually, nevermind that... Why can't you just call SUBSTRING twice within the same selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

Just select the other columns

```
new_df <- selectExpr(df, "id", "address", 
  "SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ',', -2), ',', 1) AS neighborhood")
```

This might also be possible

```
new_df <- selectExpr(df, "*", 
  "SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ',', -2), ',', 1) AS neighborhood")
```

Comment: Thanks! I receive the following error: Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input...

Comment: I might have missed a parentheses. I'm on mobile

Comment: Actually, I am also on mobile now, so I will check back in a couple of hours. Though the parantheses look fine to me at first glance.

Comment: Almost correct but each column has to be a variable: `selectExpr(df, "*", "SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ',', -2), ',', 1) AS neighborhood")`

Comment: @LostInOverflow: your modification works, great! I would be happy to accept this as an answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks @LostinOverflow that's what I get for not knowing the R api